# SQL: Showing data from two tables together

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm just starting in the SQL world, so I have a very noob question:

I have 2 tables:

- clients (columns: client_id and name)
- accounts (columns: account_id and client_id)

and I need to write a query that shows the accounts of all the clients.

But, the problem is that not all the clients have accounts, if the client doesn't have one: how can I show the `client_id`, the `name` and NULL for the `account_id` column?

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.  I also removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: Another hint: you won't need PL/SQL to do this, just SQL.

Comment: OK, I edited the post - changed PL/SQL to SQL, fixed several typos, removed the "thank U <3" (note: The standard on this site is to not include such stuff... or things like n00b - why zeros and not o's?) Most importantly for the OP (that is you, Juan!) - I changed "field" to "column" to keep with the relational terminology.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
LEFT [OUTER] JOIN clients
ON accounts.client_id = clients.client_id;
```

if not try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
LEFT [OUTER] JOIN clients
ON accounts.client_id = clients.client_id WHERE clients.client_id IS NOT NULL;
```

These are plain SQL queries, I mean they are not PL-SQL specific. `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` will only returns the columns of `accounts` table. `[OUTER]` keyword is optional, it defers from database version to version. `ON accounts.client_id = clients.client_id` will match `client_id` columns in both tables. Lastly, `WHERE clients.client_id IS NOT NULL` part should prevent the rows with `NULL` values in `client_id` cells.

Useful link: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

Comment: your second select should be removed or changed to a RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN.  Because as it stands it would actually be a INNER JOIN between Accounts and clients! However the first query should return his desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it returns the clients name client id and shows null to those client who has no accountid.

```
  select clients.name, accounts.account_id from accounts left join clients on 
  accounts.clintid=clients.client_id
```

[image: check if you are wanting this]